# Centos 7 ERROR /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifup-eth some other host already uses address x.x.x.x

Tags: centos

I've just installed Centos 7 and I am trying to create vlans in this new setup. Since this is Centos 7, it uses `ifcfg-ens3` instead of the eth0 device we're used to.

So now I'm trying to create a VLAN like below:

```
ifcfg-ens3:10

VLAN=yes
DEVICE=ens3:10
NM_CONTROLLED=no
BOOTPROTO=static
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Ethernet
IPADDR=x.x.x.x
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
```

But I get this error:

```
ERROR    : [/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifup-eth] Error, some other host already uses address x.x.x.x
```

In Centos 6.2 I was able to create vlans similar to the above to replace an older server without any problems but I seem to be stuck here with Centos7. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in your configuration:

Your device name should be `ens3.10`, not `ens3:10`. This applies both to the filename, and to the device name within the file.

The former indicates VLAN 10, the latter is an old-style interface alias name which has been deprecated for years and is no longer supported in CentOS 7 (and in particular doesn't indicate a VLAN).